# Friend c++ not working with private members

Tags: c++, friend

I tried to create a friend relationship between two classes. Following is the example:

```
class A
{
public:
  int b;
private:
  friend class B;
  int a;
};

class B
{
  public:
  A abc;
};

int main ()
{
  B b;
  b.abc.b = -1;
  b.abc.a = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

It gives following error while compiling:

> test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: test.cpp:20:9: error: ‘int A::a’
>   is private within this context    b.abc.a = 0;
>            ^ test.cpp:7:7: note: declared private here    int a;
>          ^

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `B` is `A`'s friend, not `main`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`friend` allows *code* to access an otherwise inaccessible name. However, the code which is accessing the member `a` is in `main`, and not in class `B`, so it has no special access rights.

You need something like this:

```
class B
{
  public:
  A abc;

  void set_abc_a(int i) { abc.a = i; }
};

int main ()
{
  B b;
  b.abc.b = -1;
  b.set_abc_a(0);
  return 0;
}
```